# Validation Settings

Tags: 2013

I am trying to figure out how to combine IF statements in Validation Settings for SharePoint 2013. Below are the IF statements that each work on their own but now I don't know how to create a nested IF statement. For example, the first IF statement is saying if Current Phase is changed to anything other then TBD then Total Cost Estimate is required.

=IF([Current Phase]<>”TBD”,IF([Total Cost Estimate ($K)]<>””,TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

=IF([Change Assessment Completed]=”Yes”,IF([Assessment Completed By]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

=IF([Change Assessment Completed]=”Yes”,IF([Change Category]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

=IF([Risk Assessment Complete]=”Yes”,IF([Risk Assessment Rating]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

=IF([iRCA/sRCA Status]=”Complete”,IF([Date iRCA/sRCA Completed]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work?

=IF(AND([Current Phase]<>"TBD",[Total Cost Estimate ($K)]=""),FALSE,IF(AND([Change Assessment Completed]="Yes",[Assessment Completed By]<>"",FALSE,TRUE))

Comment: Unfortunately I get a syntax error

Comment: One more try:    =IF(AND([Current Phase]="TBD",[Total Cost Estimate ($K)]=""),FALSE,IF(AND([Change Assessment Completed]="Yes",[Assessment Completed By]=""),FALSE,TRUE))

Comment: I didn't get a syntax error. When I tested it, the first 'IF' didn't prompt the error that Total Cost Estimate was required. The second 'IF' prompted the error but even when the answer wasn't Yes